# How deploy Django Project with Bitbucket Pipelines and AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a django project running perfect in AWS Elastic Beanstalk in awsgi mode.
I want add an pipeline from Bitbucket to simplify deploy process.

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: "Build and Test"
        script:
          - echo "Everything is awesome!"
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y zip
          - zip application.zip application/*
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.0
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT
              COMMAND: 'upload-only'
              ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
        artifacts: 
          - application.zip
    - step:
        name: "Deploy to Production"
        deployment: production
        script:
          - echo "Deployment to Production!"
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.0
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT
              COMMAND: 'deploy-only'
              WAIT: 'true'
```

I make a new folder called application and put all my Django project inside.
Bitbucket pipelines works fine but **show 502 error**.

#edit

**/var/log/web.stdout.log**

```
web: Traceback (most recent call last):
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
web: worker.init_process()
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
web: super().init_process()
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
web: self.load_wsgi()
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
web: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
web: self.callable = self.load()
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
web: return self.load_wsgiapp()
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
web: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
web: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

**.ebextensions/django_config.conf**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: 'myproject.wsgi:application'
```

Comment: "show 502 error" - you mean that your app, after deployment to EB fails? Have you inspected any EB logs to check why that may happen?

Comment: I updated my question with more informations @Marcin

Comment: In your zip, do you have `myproject` folder with `wsgi.py` where you create `application`?

Comment: yes. When I deploy by folder application with eb deploy <env> works fine. But with pipelines don't